# set the classpath in order to connect between mysql to jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, classpath

I use the programs: eclipse and mysql.

I have a database in mysql and I want to connect between the eclipse to the mysql.

I have some folders in my project that I created in the eclipse.

I have the main folder: testest.. and I show you what I have in the relevant folders:

```
testest
..src
....testest
......testestservlet.java
..app engine sdk
..JRE system library
..referenced library
..war
..lib
....mysql-connector-java-5.1.22
```

I updated my testestservlet.java:

```
package testest;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestestServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
      resp.setContentType("text/plain");
      resp.getWriter().println("Hey, world");
      resp.getWriter().println("MySQL Connect Example.");
      Connection conn = null;
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
      String dbName = "database_alon";
      String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String userName = "root"; 
      String password = "ADMINALON";
      try {
          Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
          resp.getWriter().println("Connected to the database");
          conn.close();
          resp.getWriter().println("Disconnected from database");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace(); 
      }
  }
}
```

now, I run testest by run as->web application.

enter the url: localhost:8888

and only see the 'hello world'.

I read about that and see that I need to write the command:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;JAVA_HOME\lib;
```

but what are the url-s of my CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME should be? I have folders of: c:/program_fils/java
and: c:/Jconnector (something like that).

the folder of Jconnector contains a file of: mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar

I tried to add the JAR into the libraries via the eclipse (right click on testest->properties->Libraries->add external jar->mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:

[image]

p.s, my operating system is windows 32bit.

Comment: Try adding `mysql-connector` to your Eclipse project build path.

Comment: @RohitJain, I tried it (and hope that I did it right) but it doesn't work :/ I added a picture to my topic that shows my screen.

Comment: @Alon.. Wait. What else do you want to see in your output screen? You  have just printed `Hey, World` only, nothing else. What did you expected?

Comment: @RohitJain, you are right! so I changed the lines of print in the code (I updated my topic). now, why didn't I see the messages: 'Connected to the database' and "Disconnected from database"?

Comment: maybe it didn't succeed to connect to the database and then catch it?

Comment: Did you see whether you got any exception? Did you got any stack trace on console?

Comment: @RohitJain,thank you but the problem is only with the driver.. I am trying to fix it. I answered Hardik Mishra, so you can read my answer please. thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need of doing

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;JAVA_HOME\lib;
```

Just add `mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:` to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Eclipse is smart enough to recognize .jar files added under `/WEB-INF/lib` and should include in the CLASSPATH.

Adding a library using "`Add External Jar`" should also work but its not best practice.

Dropping ".jar" inside `/WEB-INF/lib` will also work when you externally deploy your web apllication using `.war`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work :/
I found an answer to my problem:

"dropping the mysql .jar in appengine-java-sdk-x.x.x/lib/impl." but where can I find the appengine-java-sdk-x.x.x/lib/impl ?

Comment: @AlonShmiel: I think the problem is because you are using Google App Engine. Otherwise this is the only thing required

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar` to `WE-INF\LIB` should resolve this issue. Adding jar file via

> properties -> build path -> add external jar

is not a sure shot siolution as various platforms of Eclipse behave differently. However adding the above mentioned jar file should surely make the JDBC program work.