# Error or wrong type of code while creating connection & execute SQL query statements using mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, macos

I'm using MySQL 5.7 with Java in Eclipse, and the connection statement below code below is causing an error when I try to connect:

```
    try
    {
        //1. Get a connection to database
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?autoReconnect=true;useSSL=false;

       // 2. Create a statement
            Statement myStmt=myConn.createStatement();
      // 3.  Execute SQL query
            ResultSet myRs=myStmt.executeQuery("select * from employee");

      //4. Process the result set
            while(myRs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("last_name")+","+myRs.getString("first_name"));
            }
    }
    catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Where's `myConn` coming from? Also you have a random string in your code which I assume is how you've tried to create a connection but is causing errors to appear in other places in your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Its always good to copy and paste the error you are getting into your question so people can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First things first.

Code will only be used to validate the error. So you must paste the error fired by your program.

Since we don't have enough information to the problem, I will just cover basic troubleshooting.

Basic trouble shooting:

1. Do you have the driver? if not, you can download it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).
2. Next, Do you have the driver on your project class path? If not yet, you must add it. see how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442747/set-the-classpath-in-order-to-connect-between-mysql-to-jdbc)
3. Did you load the driver to the program? if not, `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // Load Driver` like that before doing anything.
4. Did you establish the connection? if not, `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DATABASE","USERNAME","PASSWORD");//3306 or port number depends on you config, same with DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD`
5. After the connection were established, so you should create a statement object like `Statement s = con.createStatement(); // Create Statement`. This will be used to execute sql commands.
6. finally, you can execute the commands like `s.execute("select * from employee"); // Execute Query` NOTE that **s** here is the variable created on number 5.
7. If all of the above were properly done but still gets an error, check if your have the database server running. In you case, mysql. Make sure there were not other installation of mysql prior to your current mysql. Sometimes, it will mess up your database. Troubleshooting your mysql, see mysql official doc [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/starting-server-troubleshooting.html)
8. While possible error is the datatype of mysql to your java code or getting a column that does not exist on your query or worse the column does not exist on your table.

Hope that help you and other who needs it.